# How to flip color ramp HSV Far colors

Tags: node-editor, shaders, color, shader-nodes, procedural

I'm working on a glass dispersion node group based off of this brilliant tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEPZ1IUkoB4
I need to flip the colors on the colorramp so that its a gradient from red, violet, blue, green, etc. instead of a gradient from red, yellow, green, blue, etc.

[image]

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use "near" instead of "far" and add manual stops as you like:

[image]